# Longitude and Latitude coverage for the city of Porto

Tags: data-request, geospatial, europe, geocoding, portugal

I would like to have an idea of precise coverage (extend) for the latitude/longitude of the city of Porto, Portugal.

This is in connection with my research that I need to filter out geolocation data for the cities of Porto (Portugal) and Beijing (China). Luckily, I found one for Beijing city [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Beijing#:%7E:text=Beijing%20is%20a%20municipality%20located,to%20the%20east%20and%20south.) as "ranges from 39° 27' to 41° 03' N and in longitude from 115° 25' to 117° 30' E" which is what I want.

For the city of Porto, all I get is a one-point coordinates (41.1579° N, 8.6291° W).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a precise border of the city of Porto in coordinates, then extract a city boundary. Check these pages [Getting city boundaries from openstreetmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658585/getting-city-boundaries-from-openstreetmap) and [Getting polygon boundaries of City in JSON from Google Maps API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183248/getting-polygon-boundaries-of-city-in-json-from-google-maps-api)

If only a rectangular, it is [a boundig box](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_Box), and you can get it here [Getting bounding-box of city](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440102/getting-bounding-box-of-city).

```
-8.691294,41.138351,-8.552009,41.185935
```

Both cases are also possible with [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/).

---

**References:**

[Overpass API/Overpass API by Example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example)